# how to check all rows for coincidence(sqlite)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

i need to check if user is already registred by checking all id rows in sql db, how to do it?

if i make like this:

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID from USERS")
for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == message.from_user.id:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'already registed')
```

he checking only 1st row

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code isn't checking all the rows, that's what `for row in cursor:` should do.

But it's more efficient to use a `WHERE` clause to just search for the specific rows you want.

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from USERS WHERE id = ?", (message.from_user.id,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row[0] > 0:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'already registered')
```